# Show/ hide multiple divs with closing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I almost give up. Can't find any solution on this so I hope you can help me. I have a script that shows/hides divs and it's working like this. If you click one button a div shows and if you press another button it switches to that div. That's working great. But I want to be able to close all divs with the last button clicked.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="hidden-divs-buttons">                   
    <a class="show-div btn" target="1">Div 1</a>
    <a class="show-div btn" target="2">Div 2</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden-divs">
    <div id="div1" class="target-div">Content div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="target-div">Content div 2</div>
</div>
```

This script works but has no closing functionality

```
$('.show-div').click(function() {
  $('.target-div').hide();
  $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).fadeIn(1000);        
});
```

And this is the script I want to replace the working script with. I have been trying to change it to work with closing function. I might be totally of but hopefully you guide in the right direction. I get an error that tell me "box.hasClass() isn't a function".

```
$('.show-div').click(function() {
  var box = $('#div' + $(this).attr('target'));
  $('.target-div').hide();

  if(box.hasCLass('close-div')) {
      box.removeClass('close-div');
      $('.target-div').fadeOut(1000);
  } else {
      box.fadeIn(1000);
      box.addClass('close-div');
  }

});
```

*Edit* Id's are updated.

This is how the code became. With this code I can click on a button and show a div, click the next one to show another div. If I click the same button again it will close all divs.

```
$('.show-div').click(function() {
  var box = $('#div' + $(this).attr('target'));  

  if(box.hasClass('close-div')) {
      $('.target-div').removeClass('close-div');
        $('.target-div').fadeOut(1000);   
  } else {
      $('.target-div').removeClass('close-div');
      $('.target-div').hide();
      box.fadeIn(1000);
      box.addClass('close-div');
  }   
});
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: hasClass does not have a capital L - it's `hasClass` not `hasCLass` not sure if this is just a typo in the question or your real code

Comment: Sorry, the ID:s are unique. I created a simplified HTML for this page and missed to change the ID.

Comment: Please insert `console.log(box);` after `var box = $('#div' + $(this).attr('target'));` and tell us what it outputs.

Comment: When I change the capital L that I've missed the error is gone. The script still not working as I want. I hope I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in `if(box.has[CL]ass('close-div')) {`
**hasClass** not **hasCLass**

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer! Please do not answer any typos in future. Better comment them and flag to close it :)

Comment: ...40 remaining ;)

Answer (score 1):

hasClass does not have a capital L - it's `hasClass` not `hasCLass` not sure if this is just a typo in the question or your real code.

Also both your divs in the `hidden-divs` section have the same `id` of `div1`, when they should presumably be `div1` and `div2`. In any event it would be better to specify the full id of the div as the target instead of building it.

In addition, you are applying `hide` to all elements of class `target-div` before fading them out, which rather defeats the idea of a fadeout

```html
<div class="hidden-divs-buttons">                   
    <a class="show-div btn" target="div1">Div 1</a>
    <a class="show-div btn" target="div2">Div 2</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden-divs">
    <div id="div1" class="target-div">Content div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="target-div">Content div 2</div>
</div>
```

```javascript
$('.show-div').click(function() {
  var box = $('#' + $(this).attr('target'));

  // this makes them invisible, so fadeOut is pointless
  $('.target-div').hide(); 

  if(box.hasClass('close-div')) {
      box.removeClass('close-div');
      $('.target-div').fadeOut(1000);
  } else {
      box.fadeIn(1000);
      box.addClass('close-div');
  }

});
```

Comment: The code didn't work as I hoped so I had to change a lot of it to work. But the big issue was the typo that I didn't see. Thanks's for your help!